# Android AlertDialog with image inside

Tags: android

I'm retrieving an Uri from an activity (via startActivityForResult) and I'd like to display it in a dialog but I can't get it to work, I get a NullPointerException for the ImageView when I try to set its URI.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_dialog, null);
    adb
        .setTitle("Confirm picture?")
        .setView(view)
        .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                uploadDocument(imageUri);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });

    AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();
    // This fails:
    ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview)).setImageURI(imageUri);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Did I miss something?

EDIT:

I also tried retrieving the bitmap directly from the intent, as stated in the Android doc (https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

But I get the samre result (empty/blank space).

Answer (score 1):

Use the View object to refer to the element in the layout

```
 ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview)).setImageURI(imageUri);
```

Comment: Tried that already, it doesn't work, I just have a blank (white) space instead of the picture: https://t58i.imgup.net/Screenshot3b5f.png

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview));
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
       .resize(imgWidth, imgHeight)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I don't know what Picasso is, but i'd like to do that without having to use any library, IMO it should be possible it doesn't seem that complicated.

Comment: Picasso is a library to load image. You can also try with Glide

(Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);)

Answer (score 0):

I think is best idea create a custom dialog using DialogFragment.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html